# Can I use LINQ in C# to access WSUS Collections

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a small program to handle Windows Updates on Windows Server Update Services (WSUS). Although this is a general question, I will give a specific example.

GetComputerTargetGroups() returns a ComputerTargetGroupCollection
What I would like to do is something like:

```
ComputerTargetGroupCollection c = // get the collection.
Guid guid = c.Single(tg => tg.Name == "Some Name").Id
```

But this doesn't appear to be possible. An I right it's not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get `.Single` to work because the collection does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`. To fix it you need to cast the type of the items in the collection first.

```
Guid guid = c.Cast<IComputerTargetGroup>().Single(tg => tg.Name == "Some Name").Id
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks for your response.

Comment: If I solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I must be blind - I looked all over for a box to check it as an answer - old age setting in.
O confused myself earlier by failing to spot the difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>
I generally use Generic Collections. Thanks again.